# A generics confusion: deceiving the compiler

Tags: java, generics

Consider a code:

```
public class GenericsConfusion {
    public static <T> Class<T> get(Class<T> clazz) {
        Map<Class, Class> map = new HashMap<Class, Class>();
        map.put(Integer.class, String.class);
        return map.get(clazz);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<Integer> clazz = get(Integer.class);
        System.out.println(clazz);
    }
}
```

It compiles and runs perfectly. The idea was to return in get method the class which has the same type parameter as input class. But it is broken due to the presence of map.
Yes, I know that in runtime the type parameter information is erased, so without the type parameters this code is perfectly valid. Also I know I can fix it by specifying `Map<Class<T>, Class<T>>` But the fact is that in method signature I have type parameters, and they dont help me in compile time.

Is this a misuse of some concept?

Or it is a disadvantage of Java generics?

Or its perfectly ok and I misunderstand the idea of type parameters?

Comment: It's a sign of weakness in the Java type system, which came about when type parameters were added to the language, but without forbidding raw types for backwards compatibility.

Comment: javac *does* warn of unchecked or unsafe operations in this code.

Comment: Although it compiles and runs correctly, there is one warning in the code: `Unchecked assignment: 'java.lang.Class' to 'java.lang.Class<T>' less... (Ctrl+F1) JDK 5.0 only. Signals places where an unchecked warning is issued by the compiler, for example: void f(HashMap map) { map.put("key", "value"); }`

Comment: Yeah, I'd call this *ignoring*, not *deceiving*, the compiler. The compiler knows what's up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A *raw type*, such as `Class` or `Map` (as opposed to `Class<...>` or `Map<..., ...>`), circumvents the type-checking of generics. You can even write something like this:

```
final Class<Integer> whoops = (Class) String.class;
```

This is an unfortunate weakness in the type system. It was originally included in Java 5 (which introduced generics) for compatibility with code written under previous versions.

For the most part, you can avoid this weakness by avoiding the use of raw types. Your compiler should warn you about them.

Unfortunately, there are various circumstances where raw types are essentially unavoidable (due to the special typing of `.getClass()`; due to the fact that we can only write (for example) `Map.class` and not `Map<String, String>.class` (or `Map.<String, String>class`); due to erasure and reflection, etc.); but happily, as you've noted, your circumstance does not appear to be one of these.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you were going to return something from the Map?

At present, you could theoretically store something other than `Class<T>` in the Map such as `Class<Y>`, though not from this code but leaked references etc. To return something from the Map as a `Class<T>` you must force the map to store only `Class<T>` and nothing else.

At present, it could store a `Class<T>` and a `Class<Y>` at the same time I believe.